# Glass - how do you keep an adb install'd apk app running after auto-sleep

Tags: google-glass

I've been able to get my apk's to run on Glass, but I have to use adb shell am to start it.

Glass auto-sleeps after a few seconds - how do I start my app from device, or keep it running after glass auto sleeps?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible: you will need to prevent the screen from going to sleep.

There are a few options to do that, the easiest is by using the [`android:keepScreenOn`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3akeepScreenOn) attribute in your `View` declaration.